# Generating text fields in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's suggest situation: EAV data model (generic). Exists entities table, attributes table and values table. I've made scaffoding for all of this stuff. Next, we're going to the Values->New page. It creates new Value in Values table. Here I have `entity_id` and `attribute_id` fields. And I want to add dynamic fields from Attributes table. So, in Values controller in the New action I have this:

```
 def new
    @value = Value.new

    @attribute = Attribute.find(:all) #It is not correct, it will search ALL existing attributes for all entities, I'll fix it later

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @value }
    end
  end
```

Next we going to Views->Values->_form.html.erb and generation section is here:

```
<% @attribute.each do |attr| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label attr.name %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag(controller.controller_name.singularize+'['+attr.name+']') %>
  </div>  
  <% end %>
```

Look at this string:  `<%= text_field_tag(controller.controller_name.singularize+'['+attr.name+']') %>`
It is some not "Professional Ruby" style. It looks buggy and like crap. (But it works).

And finally, the question: How to make it "Professional Ruby Style", maybe it must looks like `f.text_field attr.name` (It does'nt works). How to be? :)

Comment: P.S. Please, don't ask, why I use EAV - it's unavoidable necessary

Comment: You'd either write a helper, or extend the default formbuilder class.

Comment: Helper? Hmm, it's idea, but there is no solution "from box"?

Comment: Actually speaking, there is no need for controller.controller_name.singularize. It can be changed to simple `value[+attr.name+]`